# How to get and use a transient instance?

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I'm just trying to use a transient instance of a domain class in a controller. The transient instance is essentially a cross-product of two persistent instances, and I don't need or want to persist it.  However, I am still getting a TransientObjectException.  Is there no way to instantiate an object for a little bit just for convenience and then throw it away without persisting it?

This is grails 2.2.0.  Thanks!

**Okay**, adding some codes:

The class in particular that I'm dealing with is `Warranty`:

```
class Warranty {

    // ...other fields...
    Client client
```

`client` is the only required field. The `Client` class, similarly, has a `Warranty` foreign key:

```
class Client {

    // ...other fields...
    Warranty warranty
```

In the controller:

```
String name = params.name
if (name == null) { return }
Client client = Client.findByClientName(name as String)

// ...other stuff...

def warranty = new Warranty(client: client)
return // for testing purposes
```

...and that raises the exception!

Comment: `instance.discard()` should work can you paste your real code?

Comment: @SérgioMichels: okay, added some code.

Comment: The line of your exception is `def warranty = new Warranty(client: client)`? You really have a return after that?

Comment: @SérgioMichels At this point I do, for testing purposes.  `warranty` will be used further on in the controller, but for now I'm exiting immediately to confirm that the instantiation of a `Warranty` object is the issue, which it appears to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you modified your client instance, so when you create a new Warranty, it references to the unsaved client.

Try adding `client.discard()` before creating the warranty.

Comment: Holy cow... that's so obvious! I can't believe I didn't try it. It's crazy, because client isn't changed _at all_, but it works, so thanks!

Comment: Hmm, `client` is the argument to another class's dynamic finder.  Is even touching a dynamic finder considered cause to flush the session?

Comment: Yes, dynamic finders automatically flushes the session.

Comment: Just a though: sometimes when we override a getter or setter makes the domain class always change.

Comment: Ah, I do have some getters.  That's lovely, that reading from an instance marks it as potentially changed >:/  Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Well, someway Hibernate needs to know when your domain class changed. Depending on what you're doing it's better to have transient fields instead of replacing the getters.

Comment: Hmm! That's not a bad idea.  I'm having a lot of fun with transient fields in the Warranty domain.

Comment: Aha! From Burt Beckwith himself: "Never change the value in a setter or return a different value from a getter - you'll confuse Hibernate." (http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Customized-getter-td1380706.html#message1380709)

Comment: For future reference, the `client` class does have some getters that may return `false` instead of `null`, which I presume is enough to confuse Hibernate.

Answer (score 1):

You can `evict` from session so it will be not processed during flush

Comment: I've tried `instance.discard()`, which is the Grails equivalent, and it doesn't seem to have any effect. The weird part is that I can't even create this instance and `return` without raising the exception :/  I'm afraid that something somewhere within the domain must be attempting to flush.