# Get all transient objects

Tags: grails, grails-orm

We have a controller where we are trying to carry out search on a domain class. The actual search logic is handled in a service. This search involves use of `SomeDomain.withCriteria`, `fetchMode` set to `SELECT` and `createAlias`. The search comes back fine with the required results. Once we have the results we redirect to another action in the same controller which handles results. Returning from a controller flushes the session and this is where the controller throws the following exception:

> object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient
>   instance before flushing

Well it appears as somehow and somewhere in our code a domain object is created and is never saved. The error message is kind enough to show the type of the transient object but it does not inform where and when was it created. This remains a mystery that where this object is created from and I am now looking for ways to get hold of a reference to this object. So my question here is that how can I find all objects which are in a transient state?

I want the reference of this mystery unsaved object just because I want to call [discard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18239292/how-to-get-and-use-a-transient-instance) on it and see how things go on from there. I know that I don't need this object so if it is hanging around somewhere I want to discard it so that it does not end up in throwing exceptions. If someone can also figure out why and where that object gets created then that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've had this problem too, and it can be an obnoxious bug to find.  Presumably it's possible to find all transients by walking through Hibernate's internal structures, but I've never gone very far into it.  Instead, we typically debug via `flush()` and binary search: flush the session more and more aggressively until it's obvious which operation introduced a transient to your object graph.

Comment: I like that - part brute force, part science

Comment: @BurtBeckwith truly it is said, in science we do experiments because we're not smart enough to deduce the answer from first principles.

Comment: I am not calling save anywhere so I can't use save(flush: true). Other than this I don't understand on which object you want me to call the flush? If it is the hibernate session then I can't find such a method in that object. It is also not a method in http session as well?

Comment: ok I found the flush method. The reason I did not see it before was that my variable was not strongly typed. But guess what, I have fixed the issue and it was not related to transient instances at all! my controller had a return call to another action like this `redirect(controller:"someController", action: someAction)` and this is where the problem was. I was missing the single quotes around my action. I wonder how grails decide to link it with a db related exception. Thanks anyway.